# Combining multiple LIKE and NOT LIKE in the same mysql query

Tags: mysql

I have a Description that contains prices and telephone numbers. Prices are written like this "Price 10 euro, 2 euro" and phones are written like this "Call tel. 123.123123, tel. 123.123124".

I am trying to find all Descriptions that miss the "tel." in front of the second phone number; those written like this "Call tel. 123.123123, 123.123124".

In other words, check if Description contains a number after a comma and a space, but do not flag if the number is followed by the word "euro".

I tried with the following statement but it did not work:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM calendario WHERE `Nazione` = 'Italia' AND (

`Descrizione` LIKE '%, 0%' OR `Descrizione` LIKE '%, 1%' OR `Descrizione` LIKE '%, 2%' OR `Descrizione` LIKE '%, 3%' OR `Descrizione` LIKE '%, 4%' OR `Descrizione` LIKE '%, 5%' OR `Descrizione` LIKE '%, 6%' OR `Descrizione` LIKE '%, 7%' OR `Descrizione` LIKE '%, 8%' OR `Descrizione` LIKE '%, 9%'

OR

`Descrizione` NOT LIKE '%, 0 euro%' OR `Descrizione` NOT LIKE '%, 1 euro%' OR `Descrizione` NOT LIKE '%, 2 euro%' OR `Descrizione` NOT LIKE '%, 3 euro%' OR `Descrizione` NOT LIKE '%, 4 euro%' OR `Descrizione` NOT LIKE '%, 5 euro%' OR `Descrizione` NOT LIKE '%, 6 euro%' OR `Descrizione` NOT LIKE '%, 7 euro%' OR `Descrizione` NOT LIKE '%, 8 euro%' OR `Descrizione` NOT LIKE '%, 9 euro%'

) AND Now() < Data ORDER BY Data DESC";
```

I also tried the following statement but it also did not work:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM calendario WHERE `Nazione` = 'Italia' AND 

(`Descrizione` LIKE '%, 0%' AND `Descrizione` NOT LIKE '%, 0 euro%') OR (`Descrizione` LIKE '%, 1%'  AND `Descrizione` NOT LIKE '%, 1 euro%') OR (`Descrizione` LIKE '%, 2%' AND `Descrizione` NOT LIKE '%, 2 euro%') OR (`Descrizione` LIKE '%, 3%' AND `Descrizione` NOT LIKE '%, 3 euro%') OR (`Descrizione` LIKE '%, 4%' AND `Descrizione` NOT LIKE '%, 4 euro%') OR (`Descrizione` LIKE '%, 5%' AND `Descrizione` NOT LIKE '%, 5 euro%') OR (`Descrizione` LIKE '%, 6%' AND `Descrizione` NOT LIKE '%, 6 euro%') OR (`Descrizione` LIKE '%, 7%' AND `Descrizione` NOT LIKE '%, 7 euro%') OR (`Descrizione` LIKE '%, 8%' AND `Descrizione` NOT LIKE '%, 8 euro%') OR (`Descrizione` LIKE '%, 9%' AND `Descrizione` NOT LIKE '%, 9 euro%')

 AND Now() < Data ORDER BY Data DESC";
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you could work with something like this:

$sql = "SELECT * from calendario WHERE Nazione LIKE 'Italia' AND (Descrizione LIKE '%, [1-9]' AND Descrizione NOT LIKE '%euro%');";

Get all with Nazione Italia and Descrizione ", 1" but not including strings containing euro.

Comment: Thanks, The same string may contain both however. Wouldn't the query you suggested not flag a Description like this?

"Price 10 euro, 2 euro. Call tel. 123.123123, 123.123124".

Comment: In other words:

"Price 10 euro, 2 euro. Call tel. 123.123123, 123.123124" - FLAG

Comment: "Price 10 euro, 2 euro. Call tel. 123.123123, tel. 123.123124" - DO NOT FLAG